# How to modify a File's type property?

Tags: javascript, validation, mime-types, fileapi

So its no surprise that all browsers have a different list of recognised MIME types.

See the embedded screenshot of this [pen](https://codepen.io/synthecypher/full/MvVPpw/).

[image: Browser Comparison]

All browsers except Chrome have supplied a `File` object with `type` set to `audio/mpeg`.

In the case of Chrome the `type` is an empty string `''`.

This makes client side validation of what file types are accepted a pain to deal with. (Especially in the context when what is allowed is quite 'open' say any `video/*` or `audio/*` files.

I want to polyfill the `type` on the `File` object when it comes up blank in browsers. This will allow me to more consistently validate whether a file is of the allowed types.

However, the `type` attribute on `File` is read-only. So it cannot be modified.

Is there a way to bypass this limitation?

Such as creating a copy of the `File` object and overriding the `type`?

Comment: Perhaps not bother & just look at the extension?  That's all the browser does when it works out the mime type.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this with the following.

```
let polyfillMimetype
for (let i = 0; i < $newFiles.length; i++) {
  if (!$newFiles[i].type) {
    polyfillMimetype = mimetype.lookup($newFiles[i].name)
    $newFiles[i] = new window.File([$newFiles[i]], $newFiles[i].name, { type: polyfillMimetype })
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `polyfillMimetype` and `mimetype.lookup`?